# Why does getenv() return a non-const string

Tags: c++, operating-system, environment-variables, c++14

I was reading documentation for the `std::getenv()` function on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) and it says

> Modifying the string returned by getenv invokes undefined behavior.

Then why does the function not return a `const char*`?

Comment: I was always wondering about this too... But it got a little better in the last 25 years... I remember the time, when fopen() expected a pointer to a writeable string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Then why does the function not return a `const char*`?

Probably because of compatibility with older c standards that don't support `const` at all.

Comment: There seem to be so many issues caused by the need for backwards compatibility

Comment: @Curious Well, it's POSIX at least.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Yes.  In the v7 Unix (c. 1979) implementation, `getenv()` returned a pointer to the memory where the environment string was placed when the program was launched.  This was beside the program arguments and below that was the argv[] array.  The memory layout was (top of stack) args to main(), argv[], argv contents, envp[] array, envp contents (bottom of stack).

Comment: as far as I remember, ANSI C is very old -- I used it in the early 90s. A simple #ifdef __STDC__ could solve this problem for whoever is still using a compiler which does not understand ANSI C or C++.

Comment: @wallyk That's awesome!  I have no idea where you guys get all this information from.. Could you tell me some place I can go to read about the relevant parts of the POSIX standard?

Comment: @Curious Here's a probably useful resource: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getenv.html

Comment: @Curious [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) has a lot on the POSIX standard, as well you can find more here: [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) as well as at [unix.org](http://www.unix.org/version3/ieee_std.html)

Comment: @Curious:  `getenv()` predates POSIX by 15-20 years so don't expect to learn anything from an early implementation.

Comment: `#define const` :)