# Using constexpr together with getenv (or alternative)

Tags: c++, c++11, environment-variables, constexpr

I'm trying to capture environment variables from a build server as compile time constants that can be used within the build library. I have a static class that can be queried for these constants and would like to use `constexpr` with `std::getenv`, but I get the errors that constexpr variable must be initialised from a constant expression due to the fact that `getenv` returns a non-const `char*`, due to the fact it is [a little long in the tooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827942/why-does-getenv-return-a-non-const-string).

I'd like to avoid bloating the build scripts by injecting all of the env vars as `-DMY_ENV_VAR` if possible. If the answer is simply "no, you must add each as a definition like that", and there are no modern alternatives to `getenv` or tricks I can use then so be it, but then there are 2 spots to maintain, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The runtime environment of a C++ program, which `getenv` interacts with, is fundamentally not compile-time constant.

The `char*` vs `const char*` issue you pointed out has nothing to do with this problem.

Compile-time constants are things that are fixed at compile-time.  Your runtime environment is not fixed at compile-time.  So `getenv`'s return values *cannot* be `constexpr`.

You could create script that writes a header containing the build-time environment variables you want to store in `constexpr` storage, instead of a pile of `-D` commands.

Comment: Aha - I'm using a CMake build system where I do stuff like that with assets already. Generating a header is a nice option

Answer (score 0):

I don't think std::getenv can be used as a constexpr since it's a runtime system call. What do you mean by "there would be 2 spots to maintain"? Your static class would just use the defines passed into build, i.e.

```
class CBuildConsts
{
    public:
    static const std::string Thing;
}
```

and then in the .cpp file

```
const std::string CBuildConsts::Thing = std::string("MY_ENV_VAR");
```

Comment: Yep - but that picks up the env var from the target machine and not the build serve at compile time

Comment: @learnvst - no, it should pick it up from the build machine. In the example above, you're not calling getenv in code, you are just referring to the define which gets set at build time. So your command line to the build might look like: gcc -DMY_ENV_VAR=$MY_ENV_VAR, that should pick up the environment variable from the build machine.